# get method on Future of CompletableFutures

Tags: java, multithreading, future, completable-future

I'm doing some multi-threading work in java and I have a question about the Future `get` method.

I have an `ExecutorSevice` which submits n Callable. The submit returns a `Future` which is added to a list (later on some code). The Callable's `call` method loops through a list, and for every item of the list `someMethod` is called and returns a `CompletableFuture<T>`. Then, the Completable future is added to a map.

At the end of the loop `call` returns the map containing a bunch of CompletableFuture.

So, the initial list (`uglyList`) contains n maps of `<String, CompletableFuture<String>>`.

My question is, when I call `get` on a element of `uglyList` the execution is blocked until the entire list (passed as parameter to the Callable) is visited and all `CompletableFutures` have been inserted in the map, right?

Because, I have a doubt, is it possible that the `get` in this example, also waits the completion of the `CompletableFutures` in the map? I don't know how to test this

```
public class A {

    private class CallableC implements Callable<Map<String, CompletableFuture<String>>> {
        private List<String> listString;

        Map<String, CompletableFuture<String>> futureMap;

        public CallableC(List<String> listString) throws Exception {        
            this.listString = listString;
            this.futureMap = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, CompletableFuture<String>> call() throws Exception {

            for (int j = 0; j < listString.size(); ++j) {
                CompletableFuture<String> future = someMethod();        
                futureMap.put(listString.get(i), future);
            }

            return futureMap;
        }
    }


    public void multiThreadMethod(List<String> items) throws Exception {

        List<Future<Map<String, CompletableFuture<String>>>> uglyList = new ArrayList<>();

        int coresNumber = (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

                // This method split a List in n subList
        List<List<String>> splittedList = split(items, coresNumber);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(coresNumber);

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < coresNumber; ++i) {
                threads.add(executor.submit(new CallableC(splittedList.get(i),)));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < coresNumber; ++i) {
                uglyList.get(i).get(); //here
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
                     // YAY errors
        }
        finally {
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when i call get on a element of uglyList the execution is blocked until the entire list (passed as parameter to the Callable) is visited and all CompletableFutures have been inserted in the map, right?

Yes that is correct. The `get()` will wait for the completion of the `Callable`, which in your case means the end of the `CallableC#call()` method, which will be reached at the end of the for loop, when the `CompletableFutures` are all created and inserted into `futureMap`, regardless of the status / completion of those `CompletableFuture`s.

> it is possible that the get in this example, also waits the completion of the CompletableFutures in the map?

It is possible to achieve this, but not without additionnal code.

The minimal way to do this in your code would be to add a join call on the `CompletableFuture`s inside the tasks.

```
@Override
    public Map<String, CompletableFuture<String>> call() throws Exception {

        for (int j = 0; j < listString.size(); ++j) {
            CompletableFuture<String> future = someMethod();        
            futureMap.put(listString.get(j), future);
        }
        // This will wait for all the futures inside the map to terminate
        try {
            CompletableFuture.allOf(futureMap.values().toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
        } catch (CompletionException e) {
            // ignored - the status will be checked later on
        }

        return futureMap;
    }
```

Another way would be to wait at the very end (I skip exception handling for brevity) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < coresNumber; ++i) {
    threads.add(executor.submit(new CallableC(splittedList.get(i),)));
}
// This will wait for all the futures to terminate (thanks to f.get())
// And then, all the completable futures will be added to an array of futures that will also be waited upon
CompletableFuture.allOf(
    uglyList.stream().flatMap(f -> f.get().values().stream()).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)
).join();
```

But if possible for you, I'd simplify the whole code by using only completable futures, unless you have a very good reason to break tasks the way you do (using a list of list, a dedicated executor, etc...). This could look like this (maybe a few typos)

```
List<String> items = ...
ConcurrentMap<String, String> resultsByItem = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Future<Void> allWork = CompletableFuture.allOf(
    items.stream()
        .map(item -> someWork(item) // Get a completable future for this item
                     .andThen(result -> resultsByItem.put(item, result)) // Append the result to the map
        ).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)
);
allWork.join();
// Your futureMap is completed.
```

This would replace your *whole* code in the question.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. I divide the list of items in order to process it using multithread, I need to be sure that an item is accessed only once by one and only thread.